# WHERE clause does not work, does not return the desired values

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Take a look at my request. I am explicitly specifying the parameter, but the request does not return the correct result.
I know that there are many topics with this problem, but I have not seen such requests as mine.
Please help.

```
items = new ArrayList<>();
        items_test = new ArrayList<>();
        db = getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase("budget_app.db", MODE_PRIVATE,
                null);
//
        Cursor queryt = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM budget;", null);
        if (queryt.moveToFirst()) {
            while (queryt.moveToNext()) {
                String type = queryt.getString(0);
                String name = queryt.getString(1);
                String date = queryt.getString(2);
                Integer value = queryt.getInt(3);

                items_test.add(0, name);
            }
        }
        Log.d("Check", String.valueOf(items_test));


        Cursor queryt2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM budget WHERE name = \"loh\"", null);
        if (queryt2.moveToFirst()) {
            while (queryt2.moveToNext()) {
                String type = queryt2.getString(0);
                String name = queryt2.getString(1);
                String date = queryt2.getString(2);
                Integer value = queryt2.getInt(3);

                items_test2.add(0, name);
            }
        }
        Log.d("Check", String.valueOf(items_test2));
```

Here is my output:

[image]

Comment: @Angel Koh, ty, but i still get null

Comment: @Angel Koh, yes, you are right, now I get an empty list, but still?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like name = 'loh' not with " ?

Comment: @Angel Koh, no, I closed everything - it didn't help

Comment: @ javdromero, no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the bug.

you are calling

```
if (queryt2.moveToFirst()) {
        while (queryt2.moveToNext()) { 
    ...
```

this moves your cursor to the second position (index 1)

i.e. if you change your code to "where name in ('loh', 'fju');"  you should get only one result instead of two using your existing codes.

instead you can try

```
 queryt2.moveToFirst();
 while(!queryt2.isAfterLast()) {
    ...
    queryt2.moveToNext();
 }
```

also remember to close your cursors after using. (or use the try-with-resources)

Comment: you can also skip the moveToFirst(), and use while(q.moveToNext()) directly. The cursor is automatically at the first position immediately after a query.